# java Android SQL Daily cleaning tables

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I don't know how I can drop all table when is start a new day. When I log in to my apk I do this , but I does not work

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
if(dayOfMonth != sp.getInt("day",0)){
    editor.putInt("day", dayOfMonth);
    editor.commit();
    getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase(MainTableHelper.DATABASE_NAME + ".db");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the **DELETE** query without a where condition. If you want to delete the entire table you can use a **DROP TABLE** query
Like
`db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);`

db is intense of Database SqliteHepler. You can get writable access of db

Comment: Ok , but how I create a db ?

Comment: db is intense of Database SqliteHepler.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/JcfiapVLHXjSwtwaseTxGu And http://paste.ofcode.org/nPpWGJ9MpvhU2bN5iiq52u

Comment: why are you deleting db file . You should clear all table . so use delete table table no need to delete .db file from systems

Comment: I don't know what I do it wrong could you explain me ?

Comment: remove this code   SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);
        File databaseFile = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME + ".db");
        databaseFile.mkdirs();
        databaseFile.delete();

Comment: Ok , but how I create a object db ?

Answer (score 1):

for  clean the table use this function

```
// clear all list 
public void deleteAllList() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Please check your wording.

Comment: can you enplane what type wording  ?

Comment: This reads like a mediocre comment, not like an answer. "complite" isnt a word I have heard of before for example. In that sense: write full, complete sentences. Use punctuation, too.

Answer (score 0):

you truncate table db.execSQL("TRUNCATE table"+TABLENAME):

Comment: Ok but could you say me how I can create an object db ?

Comment: make a method in sqlitehelper class 
    void truncatetable() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone
 
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

Comment: **make a method in sqlitehelper class 
    void truncatetable() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 
        db.execSQL("TRUNCATE table"+tablename);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection 
    }     call these function when date is changed your table is clean;   call these main activity where u clean table  SQLiteHeapler db=new SqlLITEHELPER();      db.truncate();  it clear the table**